# ESET Endpoint Protection - License will soon be overused

Tags: licensing, anti-virus

ESET Remote Administrator (ERA) keeps warning me that my license will soon be overused.  The number of units in use, listed by License Management doesn't match the the number of computers I have listed on the Computers tab.  What is the correct way to see every license ESET believes is used?  Is my license in use count getting out of sync from my actual installs?  Maybe retired computers aren't being deducted from the license count?

I believe I'm using ERA 6.X but to be honest I can't find that information either.  I've spent some considerable time poking around the interface without a lot of luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question that needs to be directed to vendor support.

Comment: Please excuse me as I'm new to this site, but couldn't the same be said about almost any question on this site.  Why would I want to deal with vendor support when I can go to my peers for faster support?  Most of my problems are solved by the users of StackExchange.  Did I miss something in the question guidelines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: @ceejayoz Not really. This is squarely an administration issue, not a licensing issue as that question defines it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently ESET displays license usage from the cloud based licensing authority.  When computers are removed from ERA, the cloud based licensing count is not automatically reduced.  Log into ELA to manually delete old license instances.

[License Count Incorrect](https://forum.eset.com/topic/8682-license-count-incorrect/)